# I want to be able to change or reshape this list to a dataframe or table to analyse, any help? see code below. I use R

Tags: r, tidyr

```
nflight = GET('http://api.aviationstack.com/v1/flights?access_key=709b8cba703074de66ca50f1c5c69ce6')
rawToChar(nflight$content)
flight_data = fromJSON(rawToChar(nflight$content))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome KMazeltov, a small point to start: it can be helpful to check the formatting of your question as currently your code has whitespace and needs to be separated with new lines.

I imagine you have already inspected your data, "flight_data", using  `str(flight_data)`, `dim(flight_data)`, and `View(flight_data)`, but if you haven't this can be a helpful place to start.

You will see that within your data there are multiple data frames already present e.g. `flight_data[["data"]]` is a data.frame with 100 rows and 8 columns, then `flight_data[["data"]][["departure"]]` is a data.frame with 100 rows and 12 columns.

So it is not yet clear which variables you want to work with or in what way but here are some recommendations:

You can save information to variables and then construct your own data frame as follows:

```
my_first_column <- flight_data[["data"]][["departure"]][["airport"]]
my_second_column <- flight_data[["data"]][["departure"]][["scheduled"]]
my_dataframe <- cbind(my_first_column, my_second_column)
dim(my_dataframe)
head(my_dataframe)
```

You can call the `table()` function from R on any of your own data also:

`table(my_dataframe)` or on your original data `table(flight_data$data$flight_status)`

Comment: Thank you so much for this. it does have multiple data frames. I used this code

Comment: If you used this answer you should consider accepting it as well.

Comment: I didn't know this. I have done that.